# convert many logical columns to strings or factors

Tags: r, tidyverse

How would you programmatically convert an indeterminate number of columns containing logical values to string (or factor) containing the column name?

For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  wide = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  long = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
  heavy = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
df1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      id wide  long  heavy
#>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 2     2 FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
#> 3     3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 4     4 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 5     5 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    wide = if_else(wide, "wide", "not wide"),
    long = if_else(long, "long", "not long"),
    heavy = if_else(heavy, "heavy", "not heavy")
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      id wide     long     heavy    
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
#> 1     1 wide     not long not heavy
#> 2     2 not wide long     heavy    
#> 3     3 not wide long     not heavy
#> 4     4 wide     not long heavy    
#> 5     5 wide     long     heavy
```

Using something similar to

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), ~ ...))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take help of `cur_column()` -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), 
                ~ifelse(., cur_column(), paste('not', cur_column()))))

#     id wide     long     heavy    
#  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
#1     1 wide     not long not heavy
#2     2 not wide long     heavy    
#3     3 not wide long     not heavy
#4     4 wide     not long heavy    
#5     5 wide     long     heavy
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.logical), ~ case_when(. ~ cur_column(), 
                 TRUE ~ str_c('not ', cur_column()))))
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id wide     long     heavy    
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 wide     not long not heavy
2     2 not wide long     heavy    
3     3 not wide long     not heavy
4     4 wide     not long heavy    
5     5 wide     long     heavy
```

---

Or this can be done with just indexing

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.logical), 
     ~ c(str_c('not ', cur_column()), cur_column())[1 + .]))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id wide     long     heavy    
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 wide     not long not heavy
2     2 not wide long     heavy    
3     3 not wide long     not heavy
4     4 wide     not long heavy    
5     5 wide     long     heavy
```